# Javascript's window.parent not working in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension. The extension page has iframe that loads server, that redirects to page A and extension inject javascript to page A. Why can't i use window.parent in javascript injected to page A? It appears to be undefined. Javascript is a content_script and i have page A included in permissions. thanks for help!

Comment: what would window.parent point to anyhow? are you trying to reach the top.document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by the wording of your question, so I'll try to answer a few general cases.
I think B is probably most relevant here.

A.
If you are opening page A in a browser tab, window.parent will not refer to the extension page (if that's what you are trying to access)

B.
If you are trying to access a function on the extension page from the iFrame (if the iFrame is what is getting redirected to page A), for instance: `window.parent.someFunction(){}`, you can only use `window.parent` if that code is in the iFrame (I think page A in this case), because Chrome sandboxes injected code, meaning that you cannot access the variables and functions present in the page code with the injected code, but you can still manipulate the DOM of the page. This may be why `window.parent` appears undefined to your injected code.

Comment: You coule probably include the function you need in the injected code (though you won't be able to access vars of the extension or page A), or in the iFrame (if you want var access and the iFrame knows when to execute it). Or, here's an interesting idea, though it is not very secure, you could sign the variables and code you need into hidden DOM elements in page A with the injected code (because the code injector itself _does_ have access to extension page variables, just add them to the string you are injecting), then parse and execute them with the injected code at the time of your choosing.